# Reading parts of binary data in a string in Python

Tags: python, string, file, binary

When you use the `.read(n)` method on a file object in python you get n amount of bytes back.
What if I first load a file in a string, is there some function that lets me do the same thing?

Because I guess it's not as easy filestring[0:5], because of different types of encoding.
(And I don't really want to pay attention to that, the file read can be a text file in any format or a binary file)

Comment: You want to read N bytes from a string? Why didn't slicing work? A byte is a byte...irrespective of encoding of the data.

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Please provide an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If string is type `str` (not a Unicode string, type `unicode`), then it's a byte string and slicing will work as expected:

```
prefixed_bits = "extract this double:\xc2\x8eET\xfb!\t@"
pos = prefixed_bits.index(":") + 1
print "That looks like the value %f" % struct.unpack("d", prefixed_bits[pos:pos+8])
```

This prints 3.141593, the binary representation of which is encoded in the string literal.